# Best way to update a Django-model-instance/database-table from another server without Django

Tags: python, django

Say I have two servers `prod` and `API`.

On `prod` I have a Django application running and say I have the following model

```py
class MyModel(model.Models):
    name = models.Charfield()
    age = models.IntField()
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField()
    has_birthday = models.BooleanField()
```

thus the model in my database would look like

```
name | age   | birthdate   | has_birthday
-----+-------+-------------+-------------
john   30      1990-01-30     0
doe    20      1987-05-01     0
        ....
```

Each day on `API` I run a daily script which checks, if someone has birthday - if they do, set `has_birthday=1` (note, everything above is just an example for illustration purposes).

Since `API` just is a server for daily jobs, I have not deployed a Django-application on that server, thus I wonder, what is the usual/best way to update the `MyModel` table with the following logic?

My first intuition is just to make a plain and simple `update`- SQL statement e.g

```py
from utils import get_con_to_db

con = get_con_to_db()
query = <SQL update query>

con.execute(query)
```

but that is rather error prone in case I decide to change my model in some way. Is there a better/more secure way of doing so, without having to create a Django application on `API` thus maintaining two Django applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an url with view function `do_orm_operation` on `prod server`, then you can execute ORM operation on `API server` by send a POST request to the url,
its specific implementation is as follows(core idea is to use eval,):

```py
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
import django


# Create your views here.
models = django.apps.apps.get_models()
models_names = {mod.__name__: mod for mod in models}



def do_orm_operation(request):
    """
    This method supports CURD, you just need to send a request by `POST` method,
    the post data should be the format `{'model': 'your_model_name', 'cmd': 'your_orm_operation_begins_with_objects'}`,
    Eg: requests.post(data={'model': 'Book', 'cmd': 'objects.filter(name='book1').update(name="mybook")'}, url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/do_orm_operation/')
    """
    try:
        data = request.POST
        model_name = data['model']
        cmd = data['cmd']
        model = models_names[model_name]  # this variable will be used in eval
        query = 'model.' + cmd
        res = eval(query)
        print('res:', res)
        
        # then do whatever you want
        
        return HttpResponse('success')
    except:
        return HttpResponse('error')
```

> Note:If you use this method, you must pay attention to security issues to prevent malicious execution of database operations.

Comment: That seems like a really way to do that! I'll need to set up some credentials for `API` though, I assume

Comment: What is the idea behind having `model` and `cmd` and not just `cmd = 'Book.objects.filter(name="book1").update(name="new name")'` and then `eval(cmd)`?

Comment: When we use `eval('Book.objects....")')`, `eval` will seek the variable 'Book', but we can't explicitly declare it before executing `eval`, because we may operate other models, such as 'Person.objects....'.

Comment: I made it work just by sending a `cmd` and `eval` that e.g `eval(Book.objects.filter(name="book1").update(name="new name"))`

Comment: Did you do it by declaring the Book variable first? I mean, because I may operate many models through this interface not just 'Book', it is not appropriate to declare all possible models explicitly.

Comment: I just imported the model like `from .models import *`

Comment: This is a good practice! But if you have multiple apps, you may need to import them all.